# how to Store english characters in an array without duplicating (trying to solve Play Fair Cypher encryption)? (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, encryption

I'm trying to solve the Play Fair Cypher encryption in java programming language. so the algorithm is starts by storing the (KEY) elements first in the 5*5 Array, then the rest of the characters excepting those that include in the key.

for example if KEY="LACOR" then the array must be like this:

```
a[0][0]=L
a[0][1]=A
a[0][2]=C
a[0][3]=O
a[0][4]=R
a[1][0]=B
a[1][1]=D
a[1][2]=E
a[1][3]=F
a[1][4]=G
....
a[4][4]=Z
```

I'd stored the "KEY" in the array, but I don't know how to store the rest characters in that array without duplication.
anyone tell me any idea to do that?

Java Code:

```
public class playFair {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        String plain, key;
        plain = "BALLOON";
        key = "MONARCHY";
        int c=0;

        char matrix[][] = new char[5][5];
        char keyToArray [] = key.toCharArray();

        /*char alphabetic[] = new char[27];

        for(char i='A'; i<'Z'+1; i++){
            alphabetic[c] = i;
            c++;
            //System.out.println("["+i+"]"+alphabetic[c]);
        }

        c=0;*/

        for(int i=0; i<matrix.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<matrix.length; j++){

                if(c < keyToArray.length){
                        matrix[i][j] = keyToArray[c];
                        c++;
                }

                else{



                }


                System.out.println("["+i+"]["+j+"] = "+matrix[i][j]);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose you this approach:

```
 //the result
 char [][]a = new char[5][5];
 //the alphabet
 char [] alphabet = new char[]{'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','X','Y','Z'};
 //the key
 String key = "LACOR";
 //use count as effective index of the array
 int count = 0;
 //fill the result with the key
 for(;count<key.length();count++){
     a[count/5][count%5]=key.charAt(count);
 }
 //fill the rest of the array with alphabet - key
 for(int i = 0;i<alphabet.length;i++){
     if(!key.contains(""+alphabet[i])){
         a[count/5][count%5]=alphabet[i];
         count++;
     }
 }
 //print the result
 System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(a));
```